# OSGEO - OGR on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gdal, modulenotfounderror, ogr

I try to install the GDAL library (to use the OGR module >> FlattenTo2D() method) on Heroku. I found 2 sources how to do this:

1. Using buildstacks with github (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git)
2. Working with an Apt file

It is not clear to me which procedure is still valid so I used both (In the mean time I heard from Heroku support that both procedures are still valid...) Once I deploy my code to Heroku it seems that the GDAL library is installed. However, when I run my python script (with command: from osgeo import ogr) I get the following error:'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'.

I then also added 'gdal' to the requirements.txt file to import the module and see if this would solve the problem. However, when I try to deploy the requirements.txt list, I get the following Heroku log error (=extraction since > 30k characters):

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
       2. heroku/python
-----> Geo Packages (GDAL/GEOS/PROJ) app detected
-----> Installing GDAL-3.5.0
-----> Installing GEOS-3.10.2
-----> Installing PROJ-8.2.1
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.11.2
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
 !     
 !     A Python security update is available! Upgrade as soon as possible to: python-3.11.6
 !     See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
 !     
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.11.2
-----> Installing pip 23.3.1, setuptools 68.0.0 and wheel 0.41.3
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting requests (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
       Collecting geojson (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading geojson-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (16 kB)
       Collecting gdal (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
         Downloading GDAL-3.7.3.tar.gz (777 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Building wheel for gdal (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for gdal (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
         × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 1
         ╰─> [710 lines of output]
             WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
             running bdist_wheel
             running build
             running build_py
             creating build
             creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
             creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo
-> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdallocationinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdal_rm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdal_create_pdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/vec_tr_spat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/magphase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/get_soundg.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdalfilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/samples
             copying gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/auxiliary/color_table.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/osgeo_utils/auxiliary
             running build_ext
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o
             building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
             building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions
             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions/gdalconst_wrap.o -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c: In function ‘PyInit__gdalconst’:
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:3522:61: error: ‘GDT_Int8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GDT_Int64’?
              3522 |   SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "GDT_Int8",SWIG_From_int((int)(GDT_Int8)));
                   |                                                             ^~~~~~~~
                   |                                                             GDT_Int64
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:3522:61: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:3631:83: error: ‘GDAL_DMD_MULTIDIM_ARRAY_OPENOPTIONLIST’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘GDAL_DMD_MULTIDIM_ARRAY_CREATIONOPTIONLIST’?
              3631 |   SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "DMD_MULTIDIM_ARRAY_OPENOPTIONLIST",SWIG_FromCharPtr(GDAL_DMD_MULTIDIM_ARRAY_OPENOPTIONLIST));
                   |                                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                                                                                   GDAL_DMD_MULTIDIM_ARRAY_CREATIONOPTIONLIST
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:3743:68: error: ‘GRT_AGGREGATION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
              3743 |   SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "GRT_AGGREGATION",SWIG_From_int((int)(GRT_AGGREGATION)));
                   |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:3746:3: warning: ‘PyEval_InitThreads’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              3746 |   SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:95,
                              from extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:156:
             /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/ceval.h:132:37: note: declared here
               132 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             building 'osgeo._osr' extension
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c extensions/osr_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions/osr_wrap.o -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘int getAlignment(GDALDataType)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2947:14: error: ‘GDT_Int8’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDT_Int64’?
              2947 |         case GDT_Int8:
                   |              ^~~~~~~~
                   |              GDT_Int64
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void pushErrorHandler()’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3352:39: error: ‘CPLGetErrorHandler’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘CPLSetErrorHandler’?
              3352 |     CPLErrorHandler previousHandler = CPLGetErrorHandler(&pPreviousHandlerUserData);
                   |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                                       CPLSetErrorHandler
                          |                                       void                           CPLErr
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void pushErrorHandler()’:
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:3169:39: error: ‘CPLGetErrorHandler’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘CPLSetErrorHandler’?
              3169 |     CPLErrorHandler previousHandler = CPLGetErrorHandler(&pPreviousHandlerUserData);
                   |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                                       CPLSetErrorHandler
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: At global scope:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:6839:133: error: ‘GDALRelationshipCardinality’ has not been declared
              6839 | SWIGINTERN GDALRelationshipShadow *new_GDALRelationshipShadow(char const *name,char const *leftTableName,char const *rightTableName,GDALRelationshipCardinality cardinality){
                   |                                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |       _wrap_SetPathSpecificOption
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit__osr()’:
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:982:65: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               982 | #     define SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS  PyEval_InitThreads()
                   |                                                                 ^
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:20291:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS’
             20291 |   SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:95,
                              from extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:180:
             /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/ceval.h:132:37: note: declared here
               132 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:982:65: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               982 | #     define SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS  PyEval_InitThreads()
                   |                                                                 ^
             extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:20291:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS’
             20291 |   SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:95,
                              from extensions/osr_wrap.cpp:180:
             /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/ceval.h:132:37: note: declared here
               132 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions/ogr_wrap.o -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include
             extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp:2852:10: fatal error: ogr_recordbatch.h: No such file or directory
              2852 | #include "ogr_recordbatch.h"
                   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             compilation terminated.
             building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
             gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11 -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include -c extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/extensions/gnm_wrap.o -I/tmp/tmp.rTYO0BrQbc/include
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_new_Relationship(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:38836:3: error: ‘GDALRelationshipCardinality’ was not declared in this scope
             38836 |   GDALRelationshipCardinality arg4 ;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:38871:3: error: ‘arg4’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘arg3’?
             38871 |   arg4 = static_cast< GDALRelationshipCardinality >(val4);
                   |   ^~~~
                   |   arg3
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:38871:23: error: ‘GDALRelationshipCardinality’ does not name a type
             38871 |   arg4 = static_cast< GDALRelationshipCardinality >(val4);
                   |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Relationship_GetCardinality(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39008:3: error: ‘GDALRelationshipCardinality’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘_wrap_Relationship_GetCardinality’?
             39008 |   GDALRelationshipCardinality result;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |   _wrap_Relationship_GetCardinality
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39024:7: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
             39024 |       result = (GDALRelationshipCardinality)GDALRelationshipShadow_GetCardinality(arg1);
                   |       ^~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39039:48: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
             39039 |   resultobj = SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(result));
                   |                                                ^~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Relationship_GetType(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39748:3: error: ‘GDALRelationshipType’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALRelationshipShadow’?
             39748 |   GDALRelationshipType result;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |   GDALRelationshipShadow
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39764:7: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
             39764 |       result = (GDALRelationshipType)GDALRelationshipShadow_GetType(arg1);
                   |       ^~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39779:48: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
             39779 |   resultobj = SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(result));
                   |                                                ^~~~~~
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Relationship_SetType(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39790:3: error: ‘GDALRelationshipType’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALRelationshipShadow’?
             39790 |   GDALRelationshipType arg2 ;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |   GDALRelationshipShadow
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39807:3: error: ‘arg2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘arg1’?
             39807 |   arg2 = static_cast< GDALRelationshipType >(val2);
                   |   ^~~~
                   |   arg1
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:39807:23: error: ‘GDALRelationshipType’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘GDALRelationshipShadow’?
             39807 |   arg2 = static_cast< GDALRelationshipType >(val2);
                   |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                       GDALRelationshipShadow
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_new_GDALVectorInfoOptions(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46039:3: error: ‘GDALVectorInfoOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALInfoOptions’?
             46039 |   GDALVectorInfoOptions *result = 0 ;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |   GDALInfoOptions
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46039:26: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘resultobj’?
             46039 |   GDALVectorInfoOptions *result = 0 ;
                   |                          ^~~~~~
                   |                          resultobj
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46059:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
             46059 |       result = (GDALVectorInfoOptions *)new_GDALVectorInfoOptions(arg1);
                   |                                        ^
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_delete_GDALVectorInfoOptions(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46092:3: error: ‘GDALVectorInfoOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALInfoOptions’?
             46092 |   GDALVectorInfoOptions *arg1 = (GDALVectorInfoOptions *) 0 ;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |   GDALInfoOptions
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46092:26: error: ‘arg1’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘args’?
             46092 |   GDALVectorInfoOptions *arg1 = (GDALVectorInfoOptions *) 0 ;
                   |                          ^~~~
                   |                          args
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46092:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
             46092 |   GDALVectorInfoOptions *arg1 = (GDALVectorInfoOptions *) 0 ;
                   |                                                         ^
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46103:28: error: ‘GDALVectorInfoOptions’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘GDALInfoOptions’?
             46103 |   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp1);
                   |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                            GDALInfoOptions
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46103:50: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘*’ token
             46103 |   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp1);
                   |                                                  ^
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46103:50: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘*’ token
             46103 |   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp1);
                   |                                                  ^
                   |                                                  (
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46103:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
             46103 |   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp1);
                   |                                                    ^
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46103:60: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             46103 |   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp1);
                   |                                                            ^
                   |                                                            )
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46111:7: error: ‘delete_GDALVectorInfoOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘_wrap_delete_GDALVectorInfoOptions’?
             46111 |       delete_GDALVectorInfoOptions(arg1);
                   |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |       _wrap_delete_GDALVectorInfoOptions
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_VectorInfoInternal(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46148:3: error: ‘GDALVectorInfoOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALInfoOptions’?
                   |                                                  (
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46166:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
             46166 |   arg2 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp2);
                   |                                                    ^
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46166:60: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             46166 |   arg2 = reinterpret_cast< GDALVectorInfoOptions * >(argp2);
                   |                                                            ^
                   |                                                            )
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:46174:39: error: ‘GDALVectorInfo’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘GDALVersionInfo’?
             46174 |       result = (retStringAndCPLFree *)GDALVectorInfo(arg1,arg2);
                   |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                                       GDALVersionInfo
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit__gdal()’:
             extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:982:65: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               982 | #     define SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS  PyEval_InitThreads()
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void pushErrorHandler()’:
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:3140:39: error: ‘CPLGetErrorHandler’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘CPLSetErrorHandler’?
              3140 |     CPLErrorHandler previousHandler = CPLGetErrorHandler(&pPreviousHandlerUserData);
                   |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   |                                       CPLSetErrorHandler
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit__gnm()’:
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:982:65: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               982 | #     define SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS  PyEval_InitThreads()
                   |                                                                 ^
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:6770:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS’
              6770 |   SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:95,
                              from extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:180:
             /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/ceval.h:132:37: note: declared here
               132 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:982:65: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
               982 | #     define SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS  PyEval_InitThreads()
                   |                                                                 ^
             extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:6770:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS’
              6770 |   SWIG_PYTHON_INITIALIZE_THREADS;
                   |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:95,
                              from extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp:180:
             /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/ceval.h:132:37: note: declared here
               132 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
                   |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
             [end of output]
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
         ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
         Running setup.py clean for gdal
         Building wheel for typing (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for typing (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for typing: filename=typing-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl size=26308 sha256=7ad5349105b142e3c06b3d1732ebfc8df0883cc868d8749af0bf8be0fb2424ce
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-0qd1bc96/wheels/9d/67/2f/53e3ef32ec48d11d7d60245255e2d71e908201d20c880c08ee
       Successfully built psycopg2 area typing
       Failed to build gdal
       ERROR: Could not build wheels for gdal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

A 'wheel' error or something to do with the python version...?

Any idea what could be the issue with GDAL not being found and particularely how I can install the OGR module that I am looking for? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GDAL packages you get via the Geo buildpack and Apt contain [the base library](https://gdal.org/), which [appears to be implemented](https://gdal.org/development/dev_environment.html#build-requirements) in [some combination of C and C++](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal).

[Bindings for Python](https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html) and [other languages](https://gdal.org/api/index.html) need to be installed separately. It looks like you'll need to specify a version of the Python `gdal` library that's compatible with the underlying low-level library being used (3.5.0). [`gdal==3.5.0.3`](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/3.5.0.3/) appears to be the latest such version:

> ### Dependencies
>
> - libgdal (3.5.0 or greater) and header files (gdal-devel)
> - numpy (1.0.0 or greater) and header files (numpy-devel) (not explicitly required, but many examples and utilities will not work without it)

Add this dependency to your `Pipfile`, `requirements.txt`, or `setup.py` file (do whatever you're already doing for other dependencies), commit, and redeploy.

The Python bindings depend on the low-level library, so you'll need the base GDAL library as well as the Python library.

---

Side note: I don't recommend using the Geo buildpack and apt GDAL packages together. They could interfere with each other. Pick one.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am a beginning python programmer so I will try to find out what you exactely mean with 'declaring dependencies' and how to do this on Heroku. What I read about Heroku is that they are not supporting the declaration of the GDAL dependency in the requirement.txt file. I tried this and got an error. Not sure how to do this in the pip- or setup file on Heroku...

Comment: @GIStrees, you'll need to do both things: Get the low-level library written in C and C++ (e.g. via apt or the geo buildpack) _and_ declare your Python dependency. Do you already have a `requirements.txt` file? Add `gdal` to it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just tried to add GDAL to the requirements.txt file, but when I deploy, I get an error code:      "Failed to build gdal
       ERROR: Could not build wheels for gdal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed"

Comment: @GIStrees, please edit your question and add this information, including the _full_ error message (there's likely more info above what you commented here).

Comment: Hi Chris, done. I could not upload the entire log file since it was longer than 30k characters. But I tried to leave the essential parts in there. I hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: @GIStrees, you're still using both the Geo buildpack and the Apt buildpack. As I've mentioned a couple of times, they may interfere with each other. Please pick _one_ and try again. See if that changes the errors.

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies. I removed the by using: heroku buildpacks:remove heroku-community/apt -a [app name]. I still get the same errors. I modified the log file in the question.

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies. I removed the Apt option by using: heroku buildpacks:remove heroku-community/apt -a [app name]. I also added the new log code. As you can see, the same log error remains after the requirements.txt deploy.

Comment: @GIStrees, thank you. I've updated my answer to say that you'll need a specific version of the Python `gdal` library. Please try that.

Comment: @GIStrees, did the updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: I still need to check Chris. Will do next week and let you know.

Comment: Hi Chris, I did add the version to the requirements.txt file ("gdal == 3.5.0") and it worked! Excellent! Many, many thanks for your support!